# Shell Script - Do not wait for read

Tags: linux, bash, shell

This is a loop which should count down 10 secs (`$rtime`).
If you want to break out of the loop earlier you would have to type <kbd>n</kbd>.
Can I somehow not wait until read gets an input, because at the moment the loop always
gets stuck at read and waits there for an input.

```
    ct=$(date +"%s")
    while [ $(( $ctn - $ct )) -le $rtime ] ; do
        ctn=$(date +"%s")
        read r 
        if [ "$r" = "n" ] ; then
            break
        fi
    done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a timeout to `read`:

```
read -t 1 r
```

which will cause it to finish if nothing was entered after a second.

Comment: Or just use `read -t $rtime r` and avoid the loop here entirely (though that will break on any input not just `n`.

Comment: Sure! But you may want to do something else in the loop (eg print a countdown), which is why I went for this option :)

Comment: thanks for the quick response! yes there are some other things in the loop. :)

Comment: Maybe this was obvious to the OP, but for completeness: The loop can be written as `for i in {10...1} ; do` to get 10 iterations, counting backwards.